# Ubuntu terminal and PhpStorm terminal shows different node versions

Tags: laravel, npm, phpstorm

Trying to `npm install` in my project but I'm getting error like

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@vitejs/plugin-vue@4.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^14.18.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'laravel-vite-plugin@0.7.4',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'rollup@3.20.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14.18.0', npm: '>=8.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'vite@4.2.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^14.18.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

When I try to check my node version in my Ubuntu terminal, it says v18.x.x. But in PhpStorm's terminal it say v12.x.x. So I am getting an error while I'm trying to run my project. Can you help me?

Trying to update node with npm but not worked.

EDIT: Tried uncheck `Add 'node_modules/.bin' from the project root to $PATH` section in phpStorm settings but not worked.

Comment: If you launch PhpStorm from your Ubuntu terminal (and not via desktop icon), will it show the correct version in built-in terminal? (it should).

Comment: If it work that way then the IDE (your OS actually) does not inherit your shell/env config for GUI app. try one of the following then: 1) https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205421310/comments/115000031624 2) https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205421310/comments/115000031624

Comment: @LazyOne i tried it but still the same.

Comment: what is the default Node.js version on your system, how did you set it? What is a result of `echo $PATH` in the IDE and system terminal (make sure to run it in the same folder)?

Comment: @lena i installed node from snap. The result of ``` echo $PATH ``` is ``` /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin ```. It is same both terminals

Comment: *"i installed node from snap."* What about PhpStorm? Installed from snap as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue and it was due to the `Add default project PHP interpreter to $PATH` option being checked in the terminal settings (CTRL S -> Tools -> Terminal).

If you aren't maintaining separate php versions in separate directories for each project, you should uncheck this option.

**EXPLANATION**:

What it does is prepend `/bin` or `/usr/bin` (depending on where your selected php interpreter is installed) to your `$PATH`. This causes any other binaries that you have installed in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` to override the version you may expect to see. You probably have node version 12.x.x installed in `/bin` and 18.x.x is installed in `/usr/local/bin`